# Apache: огромная нагрузка на процессор

Tags: apache, debian, linux

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть сайт на `WordPress`, есть `VPS` с digitalcloud.com, но, если несколько раз (буквально 10) перезагрузить страницу (задержав F5), то нагрузка на процессор становится 100%. Не знаю, почему так, процессор слабый, или апач так плох, прошу подсказать, как решить данную проблему?

ОС: debian 7.0.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего это ваш WordPress и не очень правильно настроенный апач.

Comment: @pyatak, а что там можно настроить?

Comment: Что бы понять что, настройте apache server status и в момент высокой загрузки посмотрите что происходит с его сокетами.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария:

Чтобы понять, что неправильно настроено, настройте apache server status, и в момент высокой загрузки посмотрите, что происходит с его сокетами.